# Highcharts Options to stringified JSON

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, stringify

i need to convert the **highcharts options** to a **JSON string**. And I'm really struggling with this.

Because it has cuircual structure.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8TEKD/

Well I also tried to decycle it with the douglascrockford cycle.js: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

If I try to decycle it I get this stacktrace

```
'Attr.ownerElement' is deprecated and has been removed from DOM4 (http://w3.org/tr/dom). cycle.js:92
'Attr.textContent' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead. cycle.js:92
'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead. cycle.js:92
'HTMLHtmlElement.manifest' is deprecated. The manifest attribute only has an effect during the early stages of document load. cycle.js:92
InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.
```

Well I need this because I want to **save** the **configuration** of my Chart and load it later with that configuration.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that  `$('#container').highcharts(options);` adds a `renderTo` element to your object that is a DOM element.  Before that is added, you don't have a cyclic structure.   And, if you truely want to save off your config options for use again, saving the DOM element they are rendered to this time isn't of use to you.

I would recommend saving the json before you create the chart:

```
$(function () {
    var options = {

        chart: {
            marginRight: 120
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 0,
            y: 100
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    };
    jsonstring = JSON.stringify(options);

    $('#container').highcharts(JSON.parse(jsonstring));  // just to prove it works, obviously you would use the options variable here

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6y2gg6oy/

But, if that isn't an option, you can use `JSON.stringify`'s `replacer` option to exclude the parts of the options object that you don't want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, i guess thats what I'm doing right now. Well in my case its a bit more complicated because I trying to build a dynmaic chart which updates and alters the confiugration. But I have defined some update methods that update my own configuration, which then will be converted to JSON, stored and loaded again.